# mustache Handlebars.js partial get all objects in list

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, mustache, partial

I have a list of objects (this list structure needs to stay the same)

I want to pass to my html partial all the data for example `title` `intro` and the rest from `ranges`

**My partial within my html is**

```
{{> range-list range-list-page.ranges}}
```

I need to get all data from the object list (ranges), this works if I remove `bigbob2` and `bigbob3` however I need them to call in `bigbob2` `bigbob3`
 later in a different partial.

*when I change my partial to be*

`{{> range-list range-list-page.ranges.bigbob2}}`

I get the data for `bigbob2`as expected, however I need to get the data from `bigbob2` and `bigbob3` how would I do this?

so all I need is to call `bigbob2` and `bigbob3`. for example.

```
{{> range-list range-list-page.ranges.bigbob2,bigbob3}}
```

**my json array**

```
"ranges": {
  "bigbob": [
    {
      "title": "brain patter",
      "intro": "fghtfhthd ",
      "slider": {
        "slides": [
          "//train-pool.jpg"

        ],
        "thumbnails": [
          "//train-blue.jpg"
        ]
      },
      "price": "xxx",
      "promo": [
        "xxx"
      ],
      "colors": [
        {
          "color": "#FFFFFF",
          "label": "Ice",
          "bordered": true,
          "href": "/jjhj.html"
        },
        {
          "color": "#A1ABAA",
          "label": "Azure",
          "href": "/kkkkjjj.html"
        },
        {
          "color": "#726B65",
          "label": "Graphite",
          "href": "/ppp.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bigbob2": [
    {
      "title": "hill",
      "intro": "ojhuohiuphipj.",
      "slider": {
        "slides": [
          "//image/two.jpg"
        ],
        "thumbnails": [
          "//my-image-bee.jpg"
        ]
      },
      "price": "xxx",
      "promo": [
        ""
      ],
      "colors": [

        {
          "color": "#f4eef0",
          "label": "grey",
          "href": "/gg.html"
        },
        {
          "color": "#d8d7d5",
          "label": "blue",
          "href": "/tt.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`withBefore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-helpers#withBefore) handlebar helper.

```
{{#withBefore range-list-page.ranges 3}}
  {{>range-list this}}
{{/withBefore}}
```

Also if you want to use the partial with every pair from the array, you can use the [`withGroup`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-helpers#withGroup) handlebar helper. Like this:

```
{{#withGroup range-list-page.ranges 2}}
  {{#each this}}
    {{>range-list .}}
  {{each}}
{{/withGroup}}
```